# Display the Sum of multi select checkboxes in a texfield in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

In my laravel application I have set of checkboxes inside a form.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">

        <div class="form-group">

          
            <strong>Test List :</strong>

            <br>

            @foreach($ttype as $value)

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(function () {
                        var boxId='<?php echo''.$value->id.''; ?>';
                        var boxPrice='<?php echo''.$value->test_desc.''; ?>';
                        var sum=0;
                    jQuery("#cbox"+boxId).click(function () {
                        if (jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
                            sum = sum + parseInt(boxPrice);
                              jQuery('#msg').val(sum);

                        } else {
                            jQuery("#text").hide();
                        }
                    });
                });
                </script>

                <label>{{ Form::checkbox('samp_list[]', $value->test_name, false, array('class' => 'name','sumT'=>''.$value->test_desc.'','id'=>'cbox'.$value->id.'')) }}

                {{ $value->test_name }}</label>

            <br/>

            @endforeach


        </div>

    </div>
```

Each checkbox has its own value called charge, Eg: for checkbox 1 the charge is 450, checkbox 2, it's 1000.... for the 10th check box charge is 2300...

Now when every time when a user selects a checkbox I'm trying to display the sum of those selected checkboxes in a text field.

```
 {!! Form::text('samp_charges', null, array('placeholder' => 'Registration Charges','class' => 'form-control','id'=>'msg')) !!}
```

But My issue is, whenever I select more than 1 option it does not display the sum. Instead, it gives me the value of the last selected check box.

How can I display the sum of all selected checkboxes in that text field and once I unselect a checkbox, substract that value from the sum

Comment: Please click [edit], then `[<>]`  snippet editor and provide a [mcve]. This is not a laravel issue, please RENDER the HTML and post ONLY html, JS and relevant CSS

Comment: Also DELEGATE. It is really bad practice to have a script inside a loop

Comment: But I'm assigning values to the checkboxes via foreach loop,

Comment: You do NOT need jQuery in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use class and data attribute - in plain HTML/PHP it would look like

   ```
   <input class="cbox" type="checkbox" data-price="<?= $boxprice ?>" />
   ```
2. Delegate:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".cbox").on("change", function() {
    const vals = $(".cbox:checked")
      .map(function() {
        return +this.dataset.price
      })
      .get();
    // test we have an array of values
    const sum = vals.length>0 ? vals.reduce((a, b) => a + b) : 0; // if no, zero sum
    $('#msg').val(sum)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
100: <input class="cbox" type="checkbox" data-price="100" /><br/> 200: <input class="cbox" type="checkbox" data-price="200" /><br/> 300: <input class="cbox" type="checkbox" data-price="300" /><br/>

<input type="text" readonly id="msg" />
```

If you do not like to use class class, then use `$("[id^=cbox]")` instead of `$(".cbox")`

Comment: no, this also only gives the last selected checkbox value, not the total value of selected checkboxes

Comment: Yes it does if you do it right. Please do the changes I suggest and show the rendered HTML

Comment: So change `'id'=>'cbox'.$value->id` to make `class="cbox"` appear and add `'data-price'=>$value->test_desc` or something

Comment: IF you do not like the class, then use `$("[id^=cbox]")` instead of `$(".cbox")`

Comment: It is working! just noted that you have edited the solution. I should upvote your answer but not having enough reps. thank you.

Comment: Hi @mplungjan, This is an additional thing, In your solution, I can see when a user first selects few checkboxes and then uncheck them all, the value will not become 0, it will remain as the value of the last unchecked box value...

Comment: Sorry I forgot to test the map returned something - see update

Comment: all perfect now